# How to decrease the RPM of laptop FAN

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling

I've got an Asus Laptop, in **idle** mode the fan reach **2300 - 2600 RPM** and makes an annoying noise, I did not run any program or game to make the fan runs all that way.

[image]

I thought the issue was the thermal throttling, so I changed the thermal paste of CPU and GPU as well, but the issue still present

Can anyone help me to get resolve this issue

Comment: GPU 0C… that's a problem. It's not reading the temperature sensor properly.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you for your comment, how I can fix this issue?

Comment: You're going to have to try to figure out why the computer doesn't know how hot it's running. That may be something you disturbed when you stripped it.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I discovered I can see the GPU temperature when I use Asus Tweak II, I don't know why the SpeedFan shows 0C as GPU temps